# rails app strange error, no trace, no log output help please seriously issue " !! Unexpected error while processing request:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

All out of the sudden, even after replacing my app I get an error like:

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `show' for "/":String
```

I have replaced my code with a backup from a few hours earlier, I test my app continuously when I'm building new features also by opening browser and clicking true pages, the old code from backup worked flawlessly but now i cannot get my app to work anymore

help!
any more advanced ruby on rails coders can help me fix this? thx

Full output of rails/server not the log!

```
  /Users/jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/jordan/apps/books/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `show' for "/":String
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `show' for "/":String
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `show' for "/":String
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `show' for "/":String
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `show' for "/profiles":String
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `show' for "/about":String
```

**Things tried**

- Cleaned routes file
- Restarted machine
- Removed all gems from gem set and installed cleanly
- Tested another ruby on rails app wich worked fine

Comment: No logs could be caused by troubles with your Rack. What's your version of rack gem?

Comment: thx I'm using rails 3.2.2 with ruby 1.9.3 worked before i cannot pinpoint what changes made this error popup. Rack versions rack (1.4.1, 1.4.0)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-protection (1.2.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)

Comment: have you rebooted your machine yet?

Comment: yes and place back a backup from before issues still it persist! i really have no idea where to look for this error. it seems its before the app is even executed, even accessing another controller and action still the same :( please help!

Comment: If it's happening on all routes, I'd check either your `routes.rb` file or anything in `config/initializers`. Another thing to try would be deleting and reinstalling all of the gems you're using. When you get the `Unexpected error` message, is there any additional backtrace or just that one line?

Comment: Please include the entire terminal session. starting from 'rails s'. And please include the controller method and routes also.

Comment: @opensourcechris thx it doesn't matter what controller i call 1) cleaned routes completely except the root and another one, both return same error. I can post the console output I do that now

Comment: @Emily only that line no backtrace.. i shall try removing all the gems and install them from start. Inside initializes i have not done any work though

Comment: Can you try it with the Webrick server? Must you use thin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The solution and a lesson learned**

I had a custom initializer for logging not the assets, this one messed up somehow it broke in the upgrade to latest ruby on rails version. Always check /config/ and initializers before the app code if you get this kind of strange behavior ;p

Comment: it was for me, I removed quiet_assets and all was well.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old answer, but I came across a similar error message recently.

I was able to get crystal-clear stack traces from Thin by upgrading from version 1.5 -> 1.6.1, which provides much more complete logging of issues at the middleware level.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reproduce the error, you know which action the request was handled by, you should start with that controller method, and go line by line from there.

Comment: It sounds like this is happening before any request is made, possibly in the server startup.

Comment: I guess I was confused by the line "Unexpected error while processing request".

Comment: It seems that no action or controller is hit it quits before ;( with no decent error, really screwed on this one. Hope to figure out what it is

Comment: Can you please give the entire terminal session, starting from 'rails s' also, can you run another rails app? even one with a single html view?